# How to generate a new variable that shows the frequency of observations of another variable?

Tags: variables, stata, frequency

Let's say I have a variable in Stata: house number.

I want a new variable that tells me the frequency of each value of 'house number'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bysort house_number : gen frequency = _N
```